# asp.net mvc hidden field id issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hidden-field

I always have a problem and cannot figure out a way to solve it.

For example in the scenario of asp.net mvc, user "A" has his products:

```
A1(id=1),A2(id=2).
```

If we edit for A1, in Edit.cshtml, A1's Id = 1 is just saved in a hiddenfield. We can modify A1's Id to 2 with browser developer tool, so the modified values will be done for A2 when post back to server, although we do a server side validation. But user A has enough rights to modify all his products A1 A2. So in this case, how to prevent users from hacking? I think also to show product id in the url; then user can not modify it when updating.

I am new to MVC — maybe you have some idea or what is the general method to solve this?

Comment: If you really worried about a use hacking their own products (not sure why) then [this article](http://blog.slatner.com/2010/01/20/SecuringFormValuesInASPNETMVC.aspx) discusses one techique

Comment: Just make sure you have good authorization in place. Maybe before edit, check to see if they are allowed to edit before moving forward, Also that's why i prefer using GUID(not easy for a user to predict) for such things instead of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most not be a concern, still is a valid question, how I've fix this, well simple instead of using plain Id I'll encrypt the id, the model will look like:

```
public class ProductSafe
{
  public string Id {get; set;}\\encrypted
  public string Something {get; set;}
}
```

Using what ever you like to encrypt, when you get the object id is encrypted, when you save the model decrepit it to get real id.